# Not a Group By function -- error in grouping

Tags: mysql, sql, database

[image: This is the table I want to group by]

**In the above table i want to select PRODID,CATEGORY,DISCOUNT and group it by Apparel and sports**

I used the code

```sql
select PRODID,CATEGORY,DISCOUNT
    from product
    group by category
    having category='Sports' or category='Apparel';
```

This throws me and error `not a GROUP BY expression`.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  The error is pretty clear -- the `select` columns are inconsistent with the `group by` columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you want to *order* the table, rather than *aggregate* the table.

If so, the query would look like:

```
select PRODID, CATEGORY, DISCOUNT
from product
where category in ('Sports', 'Apparel')
order by category ;
```

This returns the rows from the table ordered by the category.  Some people, when they are learning SQL, confuse this with "grouping" multiple columns into a single row.

Comment: @VarunKumar . . . Glad I could help.  It is disheartening when people downvote correct answers and useful explanations.